# Copy certain cells to the next blank row in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA and trying to do something that I feel is basic, but I keep getting stuck in the commands.

I have one worksheet "RA REQUEST FORM" that I am using as a form.  Upon clicking a command button I would like certain cells (A22, D11, C18, C19) to be copied to the cells of the next empty row of an array on another worksheet "ACTIVE CREDITS", (COLUMNS A,B,E G) respectively.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub ButtonCode()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheets("RA REQUEST FORM")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("ACTIVE CREDITS")
    DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("A22").Copy ws2.Range("A" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("D11").Copy ws2.Range("B" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("C18").Copy ws2.Range("E" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("C19").Copy ws2.Range("G" & DestRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: I am up-voting yours as it doesn't require bouncing between sheet....and it it prettier.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help!  I was losing my mind last night.  I think I was staring at it for too long!

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it works.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim a22 As String
Dim d11 As String
Dim c18 As String
Dim c19 As String

Worksheets("RA REQUEST FORM").Activate

    a22 = Range("A22").Value
    d11 = Range("D11").Value
    c18 = Range("C18").Value
    c19 = Range("c19").Value


    Worksheets("ACTIVE CREDITS").Activate
    'select the first row with not value in column A skipping the first row e.g. - Offset(1)
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = a22
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = d11
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = c18
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = c19


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with after having issues with the text formatting messing up the look of the "active credits" worksheet.  What do you think?

```
Sub SENDTOLOG_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim copysheet As Worksheet
Dim pastesheet As Worksheet

Set copysheet = Worksheets("RA REQUEST FORM")
Set pastesheet = Worksheets("ACTIVE CREDITS")

'Copy data from the RA REQUEST FORM to the active credits worksheet

'copy date
copysheet.Range("A22").Copy
pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'copy company name
copysheet.Range("D11").Copy
pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'copy credit amount
copysheet.Range("C19").Copy
pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'copy invoice number
copysheet.Range("C18").Copy
pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'insert basic status description into STATUS cell
pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = "WAITING FOR CREDIT CONFIRMATION"

'select payment method cell
pastsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Select


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("ACTIVE CREDITS").Activate

End Sub
```